# Let $\alpha, \beta,\gamma,\delta $ be the eigenvalues of the matrix find $\alpha ^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+\delta^2 $

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $\alpha, \beta,\gamma,\delta $ be the eigen values of the matrix
>   $$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &  0  & 0& 0\\ 1  &  0 & 0 &-2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
>  \\ 0  &   0       &1 & 2  \end{pmatrix} $$
>
> then $\alpha ^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+\delta^2$ is ?

Matrix has determinant $|A|=0$

Thus one eigen value is zero. I assumed $\delta=0$.

$trace(A)=\alpha +\beta+\gamma=2$

$\alpha ^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=(\alpha +\beta+\gamma)^2-2(\alpha \beta+\beta \gamma+\alpha \gamma)=4-2(\alpha \beta+\beta \gamma+\alpha \gamma)$

I am not sure how to figure out $2(\alpha \beta+\beta \gamma+\alpha \gamma)$ term.I am not going for long method of finding eigen values by characteristic polynomial since this question came in $2$ marks so I am trying to find out quick way to solve this problem.

Comment: Why you do not compute $A^2$ and taking its trace?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR oh yessss how in the world I forgot that thank you sir .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did most of the work!

Let $P(\lambda)$ be $A$'s characteristic polynomial. Then $\alpha \beta+\beta \gamma+\alpha \gamma$ is the coefficient of $\lambda^2$. To see this, write $$P(\lambda)=\lambda(\lambda-\alpha)(\lambda-\beta)(\lambda-\gamma)$$
If I'm correct, $P(\lambda)=\lambda^4-2\lambda^3-\lambda^2+2\lambda$. So $\alpha \beta+\beta \gamma+\alpha \gamma=-1$.
So $$\alpha ^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+\delta^2=6$$

Comment: How did you calculate it $-1$? Can you add more steps  ?

Comment: Look at the expression for $P(\lambda)$, and take the coefficient in front of $\lambda^2$. It is $-1$.

Comment: Can you tell me whole expression in general of characteristic polynomial of  4th degree?

Comment: I computed it from matrix $A$ via $P(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)$.